# Probability that a vaccine works on all patients to which it is administered

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

> The probability of success of a vaccine is 0.8. The vaccine is administered to 10 patients. What is the probability that none of them suffer the sickness.

Then the solution was determined to be:

$$
P(0) = \binom{10}{10} \cdot 0.8^{10} \cdot 0,2^{10}
$$

I understant that $\binom{10}{10}$ is any combination of 10 patients and $0.8^{10}$ is the probability of the vacination working with all patients but why include the the probability of it not working on the patients $(0.2^{10})$?

Comment: That is a clear typo.  It should have been $0.2^{0}$, not $0.2^{10}$.  This is an introductory example of the usage of a binomial distribution.  Also, you are mixing using periods and commas to denote the decimal point, you should be more consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $0.2^0$, which is to say, it isn't really included in the actual calculation.

The exponent of $0.8$ and the exponent of $0.2$ should add up to the total number of patients, whcih is $10$. The exponent of $0.8$ should represent the number of patients for which the vaccine worked (i.e. the number of events of probability $0.8$ that occurs), and the exponent of $0.2$ should represent the number of patients for which the vaccine didn't work (i.e. the number of events of probability $0.2$ that occurs).